# C# how to count amount of selected checkboxes?

Tags: c#

My homework project is a form, which contains 3 checkboxes orginized in one groupbox. I need to know how many of these 3 checkboxes have been selected by user, because each selected checkbox should increase the price. I don't need to know the exact checkbox that has been selected, because each one of them adds the same amount. All what i need to know is how many have been selected by the user.

I cannot use checkbox list in this homework. It should be just 3 checkboxes, not checkbox list.

I was thinking about using the list or collection, but i do not know how to make collection of controls.

Comment: `List<CheckBox> checkBoxes = new List<CheckBox> { cb1, cb2, cb3 };`

Comment: Is this Windows Form, ASP.NET, or UWP project?

Comment: Put all the checkboxes.checked in a list or boolean array, and then check if the array contains true values.

Comment: the parent control should have a controls collection which will contain all the controls or checkboxes.  You can loop through them and see which ones are checked and increment a counter.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
int i = Groupbox.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Where(c => c.Checked).Count();
```

Or

```
int i = Groupbox.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Count(c => c.Checked);
```

Comment: or shorter: `Groupbox.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Count(c=> c.Checked)`

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanks, I didn't know that was possible!

Comment: ReSharper will usually make the same suggestion as @TimSchmelter, for those that are using it.

Comment: Yeah i added that in the answer too

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this? If you aren't familiar with linq

```
        int count = 0;

        foreach (object control in groupBox1.Controls)
        {              

            if (control.GetType() == typeof(CheckBox))
            {
                var checkbox = (CheckBox)control;
                if (checkbox.Checked)
                    count++;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Why do you have to make things so comlex? Check existing answers before posting. And why would he not want to use linq?

Comment: This is a duplicate of what BanForFun has already suggested. Plus, you don't need that `c.Checked == true`.

Comment: Im sorry, i thought that OP is new to c# and he isint familiar with linq yet if he is asking this type of question, and i thought that it would be easier for him to understand if i posted my answer.

Comment: @XomRng Yeah its easier to understand for sure

Comment: Ironically, `.OfType<>()` is part of LINQ, so this being a LINQ-alternative answer isn't really true.

Comment: You are right, i kinda made a fool out of myself. Im sorry im kinda new myself. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to go about this.

**List/make the Checkboxes yourself**

I asume thus far you only worked with the Designer to create controls. If you give all the Controls a name, you can form a Array of Checboxes like this:

```
CheckBox[] CheckBoxes = { checkBox1, checkBox2, /*...*/ };
```

If the amount is variable, it can become nessesary to create the Chekboxes yourself. This is no as hard as it sounds - indeed the Designer can do nothing you could not do as well. WindowsForms works with Partial Classes where the Designer writes one part of the class, you another. What the Designer wrote is executed with the call to "InitialiseComponents()" in the constructor.

The hard part when creating elements yourself is usually putting them into the Proper Containers with the Proper Allingment.

**Keep it in the code behind**

Accessing the UI to get data is a bit frowned upon. Instead all data should be in the code behind. So there should be 3 bools, 1 per Checkbox. Or maybe a counter variable.

You can have either 1 Check and Unckeck Event handler per Checkbox, that sets the appropirate Bool. Or you have one Check and one Uncheck handler, that you use for all 3 checkboxes that increases/decreases the counter variable.

Getting the Ui informed of changes to the code behind is a bit tricky. I am not sure if you need some label updated, but whatever code you use to increment/decrement the counter should also force a re-calculation.